# convex cone affine hull

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that, if $X$ is a linear space and $C \subset X$ is a convex cone, then:$$Aff(C)=C-C =lin(C)$$.
For the first relation, I tried to prove by duble inclusion;let $x \in Aff(C)$; then $x=\sum\lambda_{i}c_{i}$, with $i\in \{1,..,n\}$, $\lambda_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$, with sum $1$; then, I dont know how to find $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ from $C$, such as $x=c_{1}-c_{2}$; col someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Split the sum into two sums: one with positive coefficients, the other with negative coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, I get it!for the reverse inclusion, I took $x \in C-C$; so $x=a-b$, with $a,b \in C$. I have to prove that there are  some $c_{i}$, $i \in\{1,2,..,n\}$ and some $\lambda_{i}$:$x=\sum \lambda_{i}c_{i}$;

Comment: if $a,b \in C$ and $C$ is a convex cone, we will have that $\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2} \in C$..could thsi idea be helpful?

Comment: $a-b = 2(a/2)-b$.